# Autocompletion is not working in the Pydroid 3 App

Tags: python, android, autocomplete, pydroid

I cannot figure out how to get autocomplete to work on the python IDE for Android, Pydroid 3. It's the free version.

Should autocomplete work?

Dave

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the premium mod version, that setting has been disabled in the free version.